# Typescript class no access when private is used

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have some code that looks like this:

```
export class Viewer {

  private scene = new Scene(); 

}
```

Then when I import it as try:

```
const viewer = new Viewer();
```

then if I try:

viewer.scene it is now available unless I change:

```
private scene = new Scene();
```

TO

```
public scene = new Scene();
```

My question is:

How can I access the property without changing private to public?

Comment: What do you think the word "private" is supposed to mean here?

Comment: Isn't the idea of private to keep the property private?

Comment: Why though? If it should be public, make it public?

Comment: I understand that but is making it public a bad practice?

Comment: @KevinPorche depends...

Comment: Someone always tells you that "xy is a bad practice"

Comment: If the act of making something `public` was inherently bad practice, it wouldn't exist. It's the context of how you use certain methodologies that make them bad practice - not the methodologies themselves.

Comment: @tyler best example:  `with(location) { alert(href); }` :)

Comment: If you need to read the value, have you looked into getters? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors

Comment: So unless I change is to public there's no way of accessing it?

Comment: @KevinPorche See epascarello's example. You could return the private value via [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), which will allow you to *get* it, but not *set* it.

Comment: There is probably a way (maybe `eval("viewer.scene = new Scene()")`), but no, there is no *good* way. (Except the getter / setter thing)

Comment: @KevinPorche epascarello just pointed you to the standard practice. Leave the property private but add getters and setters so you retain control over modification while not making the property public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't state this explicitly in the question, my guess is you want to partially restrict access to the member, for example if you want to allow reading the field from the outside but not writing it and you only need to set it once, you can use the read-only modifier

```
export class Viewer {

  private readonly scene = new Scene(); 

}
```

Another option is to use properties and creeate just a public getter for a private field

```
export class Viewer {
  get scene(): Scene {
    return this._scene;
  }

  private _scene = new Scene();

}
```